# Athena Query Returning Inconsistent Results for Struct Column

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am facing a peculiar issue while querying a column of type struct in Amazon Athena. I am trying to query the deviceField field from the userDataColumn column. However, Athena just ignored all deviceField and treated it as null, althought all rows has non-null deviceField.

column struct:

```
userDataColumn struct<
   emailField:string,
   deviceField:string>
```

**Observed Behavior:**

1. When I run `SELECT userDataColumn FROM myTable LIMIT 100`, and download the results, each row's userDataColumn has a non-empty deviceField.
2. However, when I run `SELECT userDataColumn.deviceField FROM myTable LIMIT 100`, all the result rows are empty for deviceField.
3. Additionally, when filtering on the deviceField, such as checking its length or whether it's NULL, the results are inconsistent with what I observe from the direct SELECT.

I've tried multiple methods to extract and analyze the deviceField including explicit filtering, using various string functions, and casting it. Still, the results are perplexingly inconsistent.

**Question:**
Has anyone encountered a similar issue in Athena, especially when working with struct data types? Any insights into why this might be happening and potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

**New query results based on comments**

1. `select typeof(userDataColumn)  from myTable`

query results is: `row(emailField varchar, deviceField varchar)`

2. `select userDataColumn  from myTable`

one example result row: {emailField=abcddfdfa, deviceField=abcdefy-adf12993...}

3. `select userDataColumn[2]  from myTable`

all result rows are just empty

Comment: Can you please add result of `select typeof(userDataColumn) FROM myTable`? Also try `select userDataColumn[2] from ...`.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for your reply. Added these query resiults at the end of original question

Comment: When you use `LIMIT 100`, you are randomly choosing the results to be presented. Athena uses a parallel computing model that processes multiple files. Are you getting the same inconsistencies when you don't limit the number of results?